# iOS app using Heroku/mlab as a back-end not working

Tags: ios, mongodb, heroku

I am having some trouble with an iOS app using `Heroku/mLab` as a back-end.
By doing a number of tests, I became confident that the problem lies on the server end.

Here is what I can say. Having two apps fairly similar, one working (myOKApp) the other one not working (myNGApp).
My goal is to make the app myNGApp work.

Probably the most basic statement I can make is:

When pointing my internet browser to: https://myOKApp.herokuapp.com/
I get the usual display:

> I dream of being a website. Please star the parse-server repo on
>   GitHub!

when pointing it to: https://myNGApp.herokuapp.com/
I get this:

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

This certainly shows that I have something (basic) wrong on my server code. Can anyone point to where I should look at?

Comment: check server logs at heroku. you can also use heroku cli to check logs.

Comment: That, I already did, but didn't find anything I could make use of for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still stuck, but it may be that you did not set up your keys on myNGApp. Check both apps to see if they match. There are helpful documentation details from heroku here [configuration keys documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

This happened to me once.

Comment: Thanks, but that was a while ago. I think I solved that.